# How to configure Grunt to replace Bower dependencies by its minified versions

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I am new to Yeoman/Grunt/Bower. I have a `bower.json` file that defines the following dependencies:

**bower.json**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "~1.0.7",
        "jquery": "~1.8.0",
        "bootstrap": "~2.3.2",
        "angular-grid": "~2.0.5"
    }
}
```

In my html file I am using the non-minified versions of those libraries, which I installed via the command `bower install`

**index.html**

```
<script src="components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="components/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-grid/build/ng-grid.js"></script>
```

How can I configure grunt, so it will:

1. Copy only the minified versions of the those js files to the build directory
2. Replace the HTML so it will change e.g. `jquery.js` to `jquery.min.js`
3. When not using CDNs - is it recommend to combine all the files together with the custom application script?

What is the right approach here? Do I have to define each lib in a grunt copy task? Like:

**Gruntfile.js:**

```
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      src: [
        'components/jquery/jquery.min.js',
        'components/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'components/angular/angular.min.js',
        'components/angular-grid/build/ng-grid.min.js'
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Minified versions of the JavaScript libraries you're using will eventually not be shipped with Bower modules. Minifying and concatenating is not something the package manager is responsible for, but your build pipeline.

With [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io), the recommended way is to use [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin), which will take care of all the necessary steps. You can see an example of this when scaffolding out a new app with `yo webapp` and taking a look at the generated `Gruntfile.js` and `index.html`.

In your case, you would need to add a comment around your script includes:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
<script src="components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="components/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-grid/build/ng-grid.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And make sure to have the corresponding usemin tasks in your Grunt pipeline:

```
useminPrepare: {
    options: {
        dest: 'dist'
    },
    html: 'app/index.html'
},
usemin: {
    options: {
        dirs: ['dist']
    },
    html: ['dist/{,*/}*.html'],
    css: ['dist/styles/{,*/}*.css']
},
```

Comment: @sindre-sorhus minifying an artifact should be the maintainer responsability. You have to know the artifact codebase to use the right minifying options.

Comment: @GuillaumeMassé no it's not. It's the maintainers responsibility to build the artifacts, but not minify them. I've yet to see a built projects that couldn't be run through uglify. I would be happy to be shown otherwise though.

Comment: @GuillaumeMassé it's fairly well known Prototype does some awful stuff. Don't let that drag down the rest.

Comment: @sindre-sorhus if I develop an artifact and make a release it's just more efficient to release the minified version and spare other developper building the whole thing.

Comment: @GuillaumeMassé they most likely have a build-system anyway which will concat and minify, so it wouldn't really help them much.

Comment: why would you concat released artifact ? you loose http caching.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35104/discussion-between-guillaume-masse-and-sindre-sorhus)

Comment: Claiming that minifying 3rd party atrifacts is user's responsibility is not only odd, but would collide with so many corporate practices it's scares me to even write about. You are not supposed to do that. The sheer blame-war if something goes south...

Comment: @SindreSorhus From the Angular Team, [Best Practices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY#t=1118). They specifically recommend using their minified file because they tweaked the settings just right.

Comment: No one's asking bower to minify, just be a pass through. Also, the first slide in "Best Practices" reads: **"Never compile angular.min.js"** :D.

Answer (score 2):

don't need to change the html, try [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify)

```
uglify: {
  libs: {
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'components',
        src: '**/*.js',
        dest: 'build/components'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and if the file are requested more the one page, it will be cached by the browser, it will be load faster than the combined larger file.

Comment: Where did you find out what those parameters mean? I am looking for some documentation that explains `expand` and `cwd`. Thanks

Comment: Found an example, but no documentation on each option: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#compiling-all-files-in-a-folder-dynamically

Comment: just try and it will be clear  
cwd: the target folder  
expand: compiling all files in the folder

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you are interested in using minified javascript and also having the package version in the include path is to use [grunt-version-copy-bower-components](https://github.com/hypexr/grunt-version-copy-bower-components).  This grunt plugin handles copying the bower component to a destination directory, includes the component version in the component path, and modifies referencing files (html and css) to use the versioned minified path.

Including the version in the components path can be helpful if the site is hosted with a cache (behind a CDN).  It allows you to specify long cache times for the bower components. When switching to a new bower component version the URL will be new and the cache will fetch the new one instead of serving a stale component.

An example configuration:

```
versionCopyBowerComponents: {
  options: {
    exclude: ['underscore'],
    dest: 'dist/libs',
    filesReferencingComponents: {
      files: ['dist/test.html', 'dist/test.css'],
      useComponentMin: true
    }
  }
}
```

The plugin will determine the bower components that your project is using and automatically install them to the path specified in dest.  The files listed in filesReferencingComponents->files are files that include/source the bower component.  Specifying useComponentMin will cause it to choose the minified version of the component.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bad practice to minify yourself a library that already exists in a minified version.
Fortunately, at least for angularJS, the bower package includes angular.min.js.map file. With this source map, I think it makes no sense to include at any point the non-minified file in the source. Just include the min file, leave it outside Grunt minifier, and let the browser map to the non minified source.