# How to update and include Twitter Bootstrap 3 on webapp or yo angular?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, twitter, yeoman

I used yo webapp or yo angular to create new a project, and I received Bootstrap include is version 2.3.2, but I want use the latest version of Bootstrap.

How can I update the Bootstrap package with command prompt and later update when create new webapp or yo angular, choose include Twitter Bootstrap is last version?

Comment: For anyone else trying to use v3 with angular-generator, the project has just been updated with it included. Go to [this issue](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/pull/429) and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yeoman's webapp & angular generators grab Sass for Bootstrap, which is based on the 2.3.2 build of Twitter Bootstrap.

After you run `yo webapp` or `yo angular`, you can add Bootstrap 3.0 by running the following command.

```
$ bower install --save bootstrap
```

This will download Bootstrap 3.0 for you.

Comment: D:\Web Design\HTML-CSS\Bootstrap Test>bower install --save bootstrap
bower cloning git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git

C:\Users\TienLoc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\tmp\lib\tmp
.js:260
  throw err;
        ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I received error when enforcement command

Comment: Is Git installed and available in your `PATH`?

Comment: I installed Git, but not available in my PATH and I add it to my PATH, but not solve problems.

Comment: Have you tried updating bower, `npm update -g bower`? You may want to have a look at [this thread in in Github](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/339), seems like what you're experiencing is a common issue for certain users with a particular git setup on Windows. Also, the answer I supplied above is correct and the issue you are experience now is a separate from the original, could you please mark as correct?

Comment: tks you for help, but command not setup bootstrap into app folder for my, don't change style file or folder, anyway you help correct and I mark correct

Comment: I read in bootstrap guild and command: bower install bootstrap is work, and bootstrap install in tree: app -> bower_component -> bootstrap

Comment: I think you should also do "bower install --save bootstrap-css" for install bootstrap css files

Answer (score 22):

@micjamking answer is a really good hint, but since with Yeoman things should be easier, I'll save you some googling:

1. `yo angular` - Say 'No' to Bootstrap here - otherwise it'll download 2.x version
2. `bower install --save bootstrap`
3. `npm install --save-dev grunt-bower-install`
4. edit Gruntfile.js - insert marked lines:

   ```
   // ...
   } catch (e) {}

   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-install');             // INSERT

   grunt.initConfig({
       yeoman: yeomanConfig,
       'bower-install': {                                 // INSERT BEGIN
           target: {                                      //   .
               html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',      //   .
               ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'           //   .
           }                                              //   .
       },                                                 // INSERT END
       watch: {
           coffee: {
               files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
               tasks: ['coffee:dist']
   // ...
   ```
5. edit app/index.html - insert :

   ```
   <!-- bower:css -->
   <!-- endbower -->
   ```

   and:

   ```
   <!-- bower:js -->
   <!-- endbower -->
   ```

   where appropriate - those will inject references to bower-managed resources (bootstrap's stylesheet and JS in our case).

   *update 10/5/2013:* Consider placing `bower:xxx` inside `build:xxx`.
   In our case, `bower:css` inside `build:css` and `bower:js` inside `build:js`.
   This is needed for minification to work when assembling `dist`. However I consider this approach not so perfect - see Remarks below.  I'm excused a little bit, since this is the very same way the bootstrap version obtained by Yeoman by default gets included in our app :-P
   **Note:** To get css minification working you might need changing `build:css(.tmp)` to `build:css({.tmp,app})`.
6. `grunt bower-install`

Ready. Now run server (`grunt server`) and Bootstrap 3 will be available.

---

**Remarks - Update 10/5/2013 - inspired by @Luke's enquiry in a comment**:

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16762060/1432478) I added one sub-step to make `dist` minification work.

Bower's injecting works, so does minifying, however I'm not so happy with this approach.
Reasons:

1. *[minor]* We're not using already minified resources obtained by bower.
2. Minifying ALL kinds of CSS/JS into a SINGLE file is a pretty lame idea. A better way to include external dependencies in your application would be to have a switch between CDN-fetch (dist) and local copies obtained with bower (dev). Sth like maven profiles.
3. Depending on the application size, downloading all-in-one resources, particularly JavaScripts, will slow down first encounter with our application.
   Later on the rest of the application will be loaded faster, true, but the first time user enters our page, those bulky *single-filers* will have to be downloaded preemptively.

@yao tony also hadn't found this approach cool - see the referenced question.

**Update Nov 2013:** You can use grunt's `cdnify` task. It's cool

---

Software versions I was using:

```
user@machine:~/somewhere $ yo -v; grunt --version; bower -v
1.0.4
grunt-cli v0.1.9
grunt v0.4.1
1.2.6
```

Comment: This totally helped me out.  One question though: how do you get it to put the *.min.{css|js} version in there instead? Particularly useful during grunt build.

Comment: Good point @Luke. I found a work-around, but I'm not proud of it. See my updated answer.

Comment: Soooo much for this making bower Yeoman easier.  Tried it today and in the end I didn't have bootstrap3 @micjamking's answer did it though.

Comment: error "bower-install.app.src missing" - seems like they changed config https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install, add "src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html']" after (or instead) of the "html: '<&=

Comment: @joeriks: My answer was useful few month ago. Right now `generator-webapp` (`generator-angular` relies on it) creates project with all of these configs set up out of the box (`grunt-bower-install` configured (but not installed), bower-managed boostrap3), so it's best to just say 'Yes' when "Would you like to include Twitter Bootstrap?" question pops out. Make sure that you use newest versions of `yo` and `generator-angular` though.

Answer (score 0):

***For sass Bootstrap update:***

This Works for me:

```
bower install angular-bootstrap
bower install sass-bootstrap
```

and select the new versions of both...

maybe should add a `--save`

**Note:** sass-bootstrap is bean deprecated, is now a official bower for sass version of bootstrap https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass but i dont tried it.