# yeoman/grunt-usemin not updating index.html after new js has been added

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, yeoman

I am using yeoman with the angular generator for a web app on windows7. After running yo angular I run grunt to build the app for deployment. My index.html file in the dist folder is changed accordingly with the css and js files that was concatenated and minified.

When I add a new js file to index.html for example

```
<script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
```

and I run grunt again to build; the index.html  file no longer changes the css aan js files to the minified ones, it basically shows exactly the same as the index.html in the app directory.

I also tried putting the json3.js inside the build:js comments:

```
 <!-- build:js scripts/json.js -->
 <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
 <!-- endbuild -->
```

Is there something I am missing here? Must I change something in the grunt file like the usemin section?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I repeatedly bumped into this problem and have found a solution in my case.

I am using vs 2012 to create my HTML and cmd for the grunt tasks. It seems that my Line endings were not correct, so I changed them to Unix (LF) and grunt-usemin did its thing. When settings the line endings to Windows (CR LF) grunt-usemin don’t update the index.html page correctly.

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Thanks! Line endings will always and forever plague us.

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS! I've been staring at this problem for days.  

My local dev Windows machine was removing the build tags correctly but the azure devops build pipeline was checkout out the index.html with a mismatch of crlf and lf.

I'll update when I get a fix figured out.

Comment: I created an .gitattributes file with ```index.html text eol=lf``` to force the pipeline git checkout step to not auto normalize to crlf. I had to run the build twice for some reason but it fixed the automin issue.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your custom JavaScripts are included from `build:js({.tmp,app})` section, that's why they get minified in a single file.
I'm not suggesting putting libraries obtained by bower to `build:js({.tmp,app})` - see remarks of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034513/1432478.

A good idea might be looking at grunt's `cdnify` task.
[json3 CDN](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!json3)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. The only way that I could find to fix it was in the Gruntfile under the `htmlmin` task.

When the index.html file was not changing, my `htmlmin` task was as follows:

```
htmlmin: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      //options
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
  }
}
```

If I simply removed the `*.html` part in `html:files:src`, the build worked fine. My newer `htmlmin` task looked like this:

```
htmlmin: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      //options
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      src: ['views/{,*/}*.html'],
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone. It took me a while to figure out why the index.html file wasn't being edited correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with not being able to add angular-route and angular-animate - by that I mean the reference to the files - their script tags - were not being saved to the index.html file.

I discovered it was because I had entered their script tags before the 
tag in my index.html file. After putting them immediately after, it worked fine.

Comment: You entered their tags before what tag?

Answer (score 0):

@qorsmund helped me realize that the line endings were being mismatched.

My local dev Windows machine was checking out the index.html with "lf" and removing the build tags correctly on the grunt usemin task. However, the azure devops build pipeline was checking out the index.html with crlf.

On the azure pipeline, the grunt usemin task was working correctly on some tasks like bower and css but not the angular files (ngtemplates).  The usemin was mismatching .

To resolve the issue, I created an .gitattributes file with `index.html text eol=lf` to force the pipeline git checkout step to not auto normalize to crlf. I had to run the build twice for some reason but it fixed the automin issue.

Comment: This is a comment to another answer, not an answer.