# style folder not built

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

I installed yo webapp without bootstrap then added bootstrap 3 following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034513/712005.

I can't get grunt to build my main.css and include bootstrap correctly. No style folder is created in the dist folder.

When running "grunt build" I get this message:

> Running "cssmin:generated" (cssmin)
>
> task Destination not written because minified CSS was empty.

but no errors.

My gruntfile includes this:

```
useminPrepare: {
    options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    },
    html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
},
usemin: {
    options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
    },
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
    css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
}
```

and this:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-install');
```

index.html includes:

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp,app) styles/main.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp,app) styles/bootstrap.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

References I included to the location of main.css and bootstrap.css in the app-folder were removed during build.

bower.json includes:

```
{
  "name": "gabriel",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.2",
    "jquery": "~2.0.3",
    "modernizr": "~2.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034513/712005) follow the same steps. That should work for you. I just did and works fine for me.

In summary.

1. `yo angular` - Say 'No' to Bootstrap here
2. `bower install --save bootstrap`
3. `npm install --save-dev grunt-bower-install`
4. edit `Gruntfile.js` - Do as what exactly says
5. edit `app/index.html` - Add only below lines

   ```
   <!-- bower:css -->
   <!-- endbower -->
   <!-- bower:js -->
   <!-- endbower -->
   ```
6. `grunt bower-install`
7. run `grunt server` or `grunt build`

Comment: hm. Still the same behaviour. Here's the output in the command line: https://gist.github.com/barbalex/7682873

Comment: in case it helps: the css files are copied into the text folder and serving locally usint "grunt serve" works fine

Comment: Can you attach the index.html and Gruntfile.js. Also is there a folder called bower_components in the dist folder.

Comment: index.html is here: https://github.com/barbalex/gabriel/blob/master/app/index.html

Comment: Gruntfile.js is here: https://github.com/barbalex/gabriel/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

Comment: folder bower_components exists in the dist-folder. There's (only?) a folder modernizr inside with modernizr.js

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the following error is showing is that

Running "cssmin:generated" (cssmin) task >> Destination not written because minified CSS was empty.

the place where bootstrap css file should be placed might be missplaced, so the correct position to place bootstrap css file is as follow -

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
```

I hope this would help, folks...