# bower custom build - choose specific files

Tags: javascript, css, build, customization, bower

I am continously encountering the issue, where I need / want to include a specific file from a bower package to my app, and find no easy way to do it. This is not limited to minified versions.

Example: Moment.js comes with about four different files one can choose to include. Those are moment.js, moment.min.js, moment-with-langs.js, moment-with-langs.min.js. The bower.json and the hidden .bower.json files inside the package specify which file should be included during the build in the "main" array (here's an example with sass-bootstrap bower package):

```
"main": ["./dist/js/bootstrap.js", "./dist/css/bootstrap.css", "./dist/fonts/*"]
```

But there is no such thing in the apps bower.json file to specify for dependencies. One can only specify the dependency.

There *is* some discussion on the case: I found two topics on bower's github, namely https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/368 and https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/369 and also here [How to configure Grunt to replace Bower dependencies by its minified versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761272/how-to-configure-grunt-to-replace-bower-dependencies-by-its-minified-versions) but the issue is not limited to the minified versions.

All the topics end in the same way, stating that bower, as a package manager, should not take care of the custom build process that an app requires. But that leaves the developer with the problem of having to go about bower with the majority of the repos OR minifying the packages on his/her own. There are many who disagree on both.

The way I went about the problem with moment.js is I created a *vendor* folder and manually added the file that I needed and then added a Grunt task to do it automatically. But it just would be so much easier if there was a standard way of providing users the option to include e.g. all recommeded (default) files, the minified versions or just allow to choose specific files from the app's bower.json dependency list.

Perhaps I am not using it right, or maybe it's not a popular problem. I don't know if it's some feature that should be added to bower, but maybe other devs have experience dealing with the case?

Comment: We have the same setup with grunt.  Once you get your configuration setup, it's pretty hands free.  Even if you could get just the regular or .min files, some people would want to concat and some people want to put them in different directories after.  I think it's best that bower just pulls down the repo and allows the developer decide what to do with it.  We don't put the .js files or node modules in source control.  Only the config files and then pull them down in the build process.

Comment: well, that doesn't really do it. I want the majority of the packages to go with browser defaults, using the _bower-install_ grunt task. Then I want some packages to use specific files. Now, I can either: 1) have two copies (one through bower-install, second from my custom config) or 2) edit the bower.json file on every update and every machine I deploy my app.

Comment: You could trim the fat a little bit with the ignore property in the bower.json file.  add "*.json", "*.gzip", "*.map", "*.css", "*.md" and whatever other files you might not want.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? Interested in your solution as I have a similar problem. One of my bower components has an awful css file which is included by default in it's bower.json and I want to exclude it as a dependency without having to modify the bower_components folder (since that is .gitignored).

Answer (score 0):

If you use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) it has [debowerify](https://github.com/eugeneware/debowerify) transformation that just grabs *the first* file from the `main` array. To include a particular extra file call the `require` function with appropriate path.

Comment: that's an alternative. I would like to continue using bower and not have to use npm for everything (because bower is more efficient for the browser).

Comment: Frankly I do no understand your question then. You *have to* compile all files fetched from `bower` using some extra tool. browserify is one of options. There are bunch of other tools as well. As you mentioned bower should not take care of the custom build process, and this is a valid argument.

Comment: I thought browserify was dedicated for npm modules. I use grunt to build the modules, but if bower is not supposed to be used to build, then I don't understand why the packages' bower.json file specifies which files to include during the build process :)

Comment: No, bower is not a build tool. It just helps to fetch dependencies for your project. The `main` property in `bower.json` specifies "The primary endpoints of your package.". I'd recommend you to read more about grunt and bower, they are very different by responsibilities.