# Can Grunt wiredep wire minify version in HTML file

Tags: gruntjs, bower, grunt-wiredep

Is it possible to inject minified version of dependencies in HTML pages using Grunt wiredep plugin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Grunt to replace Bower dependencies by its minified versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761272/how-to-configure-grunt-to-replace-bower-dependencies-by-its-minified-versions)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by overriding the wiredep fileTypes setting in your Gruntfile.js configuration.

The following replaces (renames) all *.js filenames into *.min.js:

```
wiredep: {
    task: {
        src: [
            'public_html/**/*.html', // .html support...
            // ...
        ],
    },
    fileTypes: {
        html: {
            block: /(([ \t]*)<!--\s*bower:*(\S*)\s*-->)(\n|\r|.)*?(<!--\s*endbower\s*-->)/gi,
            detect: {
                js: /<script.*src=['"]([^'"]+)/gi,
                css: /<link.*href=['"]([^'"]+)/gi
            },
            replace: {
                js: function(filePath) {
                    var filePathStrArr = filePath.split('.');
                    var filePathStr = ''; //filePathStrArr[filePathStrArr.length-2];

                    if (filePathStrArr[filePathStrArr.length - 2] != 'min') {
                        filePathStrArr.pop();
                        filePathStr = filePathStrArr.join('.') + '.min.js';
                        if(!grunt.file.exists(filePathStr)){
                            //console.log('warning - file does not exist:'+filePathStr);
                            filePathStr = filePath; //if the .min.js file does not exist then revert back to original filename
                        }
                    } else {
                        filePathStr = filePath;
                    }
                    return '<script src="' + filePathStr + '"></script>';
                },
                css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{filePath}}" />'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes that there is a *.min.js file in all your javascript locations.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it's not possible.

The main use of grunt-wiredep is to provide the addition of your bower dependencies easily.

If you want to minify your bower files, I recommend you to use [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) or [grunt-html-build](https://github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build). You can minify all your bower dependencies in one file.

For example with grunt-usemin you have to do this.

```
<!-- build:js js/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The working version of [EdC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34261212/7311767), (couldn't get it to work but it inspired me to write this) plus an enhancement for handling the case when `.min.js` file is provided in a different location would be:

```
task: {
    src:'public_html/**/*.html',
    fileTypes: {
        html: {
            block: /(([ \t]*)<!--\s*bower:*(\S*)\s*-->)(\n|\r|.)*?(<!--\s*endbower\s*-->)/gi,
            detect: {
                js: /<script.*src=['"]([^'"]+)/gi,
                css: /<link.*href=['"]([^'"]+)/gi
            },
            replace: {
                js: function(filePath) {
                    var filePathStr = '', path = require('path'), pattern = /min.js/g;
                    // libDirectory would always be 'bower_components/libname'
                    var libDirectory = filePath.split('/').slice(0,2).join('/');
                    var minFilename = path.posix.basename(filePath).replace('.js','.min.js');

                    if (!pattern.test(filePath)) {
                        if(!grunt.file.exists(filePath.replace('.js','.min.js'))){
                            // need to have the normal lib file in case min version wasn't available at all
                            filePathStr = filePath;
                            // recursively executes the callback function for every file in lib directory(libDirectory)
                            grunt.file.recurse(libDirectory, function callback(abspath, rootdir, subdir, filename) {
                                if( filename === minFilename )
                                    filePathStr = abspath;
                            });
                        } else {
                            // if min exists in the same dir then so be it
                            filePathStr = filePath.replace('.js','.min.js');
                        }
                    } else {
                        // some packages main attribute is pointed to min version already
                        filePathStr = filePath;
                    }
                    return '<script src="' + filePathStr + '"></script>';
                },
                css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{filePath}}" />'
            }
        }
    }
}
```